# Recommended approach for configuration management of the small but vital changes on Linux servers

Tags: configuration-management

Folks - what is the recommended approach for controlling and recording small but vital changes on the Linux servers - creation of the group, adding users to a sudo, etc.?

We use Salt for the major deployments, but I also want to influence owners of the smaller deployments to enforce a complete discipline and configuration management of the smaller scale things such as user creation and adding him/her to a sudo.

Comment: Why not also use Salt for this if you are already using it anyway?

Comment: _"Hi, we have configuration management, but want some tips on how to use configuration management"_  - I'd suggest using what you already have. If there are political, organizational or technical barriers to doing so, please describe the challenges in your question.

Comment: If you have salt then stick to it. Make documentation and so on. Also use git with  configuration management it helps to track changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why differentiate between "major" and "minor"? Just use salt for both. If you really wanted a different tool, Ansible is fairly lightweight and fast, but then you and your staff will need to learn two different toolsets and then keep track of which type of changes are made with each tool. Additionally, you have the very real possibility of the two tools "fighting" each other for changes.

Too much overhead and potential for issues IMHO.

Just use salt for everything.